# Different email contents in Windows and in Mac

Tags: html, windows, macos, email, outlook

I'm facing a very strange behaviour of outlook. From the same email sent out by our server with the following source:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="cid:Banner"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

we get different email raw content in Mac and in Windows. In Windows, the content is the same. In Mac OS, the `<img>` has been changed to `<a>`:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="cid:Banner"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm using the same email account, looking into the same email but having different contents. I can't understand this, who has changed the html content? Does anyone have any idea?

Many thanks!